# handling sharepoint login via jython

Tags: sharepoint, jython

I am trying to read files from a sharepoint folder and write into a different file.

I was successful to write a simple script using urllib

```
import urllib
page=urllib.urlopen("file.txt")
output=open('c:/test.txt','w')
output.write(page.read())
output.close()
```

The issue is that I need to read via sharepoint site which has authentication and iam not able to find the correct urllib command to pass the user and password info. 
i have even tried urlencode but still iam getting access denied. I do have permission to see the file if being view from a browse.

Jython -2.1 is being used so urllib2 cannot be called.

Please suggest any other function that do the work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What type of authentication is your SharePoint environment using?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Sharepoint are we talking about? If it is 2010, I suggest you take a look at REST API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx